# Find the minimum value of $f(x,y) = x + y^2$ given the constraint $2x^2 + y^2 = 1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier, qcqp

> Find the minimum value of $x + y^2$ subject to the condition $2x^2 + y^2 = 1$.

1) I find $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ to get $$\nabla f(x,y) = (1, 2y) \\ \nabla g(x,y) = (4x, 2y)$$

Then I set up the system of equations

\begin{align}
\nabla f(x,y) &= \lambda g(x,y) \\
1 &= \lambda 4x \\
2y &= \lambda 2y \\
2x^2 + y^2 &= 1
\end{align}

I am having difficulties solving the system of equations. I got $\lambda = 1$ from $2y = \lambda 2y$ and from there I obtain $x = \frac{1}{4}$. However I don't understand how I am supposed to solve for a value of $y$.

I tried to plug in $x = 1/4$ into $2x^2 + 2y^2 = 1$ but I got $y = \sqrt{7/4}$ which does not fit the system of equations. I think my setup is correct and I am doing the calculations wrong. I think I should be getting $x = 1/4$ and $y = \sqrt{7}/4$. What do you guys think?

Comment: By the constraint, $f(x,y)=x+y^2=x+1-2x^2$ and $x^2\le \frac12$. This way, you do not even need Lagrange

Comment: How do you get $x + 1 - 2x^2$?

Comment: $y^2=1-2x^2$ because $2x^2+y^2=1$, so $x+y^2=x+1-2x^2$

Comment: Are you required to use Lagrange here? There's an easier method.

Comment: @bjorn93 I don't think we are specifically required to use Lagrange, but I wanted to use it anyways to become more comfortable with it

Comment: Is it $2x^2+y^2=1$ or $2x^2+2y^2=1$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner It is just 2x^2 + y^2 = 1$

Comment: Textbook says find the minimum and in the back it says the answer is $-1/\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the equality $2y=2\lambda y$, you can deduce that either $y=0$ or that $\lambda=1$.

If $\lambda=1$, your first and third equations become $4x=1$ and $2x^2+y^2=1$. In this case, the solutions are $(x,y)=\left(\frac14,\pm\sqrt{\frac78}\right)$.

If $y=0$, your first and third equations become $4\lambda x=1$ and $2x^2=1$. In this case, the solutions are $(x,y)=\left(\pm\frac1{\sqrt2},0\right)$.

Comment: OP meant $2x^2+y^2=1$, not $2x^2+2y^2=1$

Comment: I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Alright, it worked out. I found the minimum value value to be $-1/\sqrt{2}$ like the answer in the book

Answer (score 2):

Actually you do not need Lagrange multipliers: by setting $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}z$ you are looking for the minimum of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}z+y^2$ under the constraint $z^2+y^2=1$, so you are looking for the minimum of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}z+(1-z^2)$ over $[-1,1]$, which is achieved at the left endpoint of the domain.

Answer (score 1):

Did you plug $x=\frac14$ in $2x^2+2y^2=1$ instead of $2x^2+y^2=1$?

Comment: oh crap. I did...let me recalculuate